# BES Vulnerability Management

Tags: security, blackberry

We try to follow security best practices by keeping software and device settings up to date and specifying whether or not applications can initiate specific types of connections, but I would like to be more proactive.

I saw a blog from eEye regarding a free mobility scanning module (http://blog.eeye.com/general/sneak-peek-free-mobility-scanning-from-eeye) and wanted to know what other people are doing for vulnerability management?

Comment: [Sitewatch](https://sitewat.ch/) is a good vulnerability scanner for web applications.  There is a free version.

Comment: This belongs on http://security.stackexchange.com/